# Reading data from the file, splitting the words and making an object

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, class, object

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
productName calories protein carb fat
```

I wanted to split the words in every row and make an object with these variables. I wrote something like this:

```
with open("Produkty.txt") as file:
     for line in file: 
        (product, calories, protein, carb, fat) = line.split()
        product = productBase(product, calories, protein, carb, fat)
```

The thing is that there's no objects being created.
The class itself looks like this:

```
class productBase:
  def __init__(self, product, calories, protein, carb, fat):
      self.product = product
      self.calories = calories
      self.protein = protein
      self.carb = carb
      self.fat = fat
```

I did something similiar, but my file had 2 words in a row and i wrote them to a dictionary. It worked like this:

```
   with open("Produkty.txt") as file:
     for line in file: 
        (product, calories) = line.split()        
        foodDictionary[product] = calories
```

I thought I could add more info to a product by using objects and classes, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: What do you mean "no objects are being created"? What's the value of `product` after the `product = productBase(...)` line is executed?

Comment: If you want to later access the `product` object, you'll have to store it outside your for loop. Otherwise it is lost to the world.

Comment: It actually is creating an object that is called 'product'. It overwrites itself after every iteration. Is there a way to name the object after the content that is stored in 'product'?

Comment: @Soumati You could add each object to a list then iterate through the list later. It depends that you want to do with them.